# Robobrowser keep an active session

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, robobrowser

I wrote a code that has as mission to log in a system, to stay logged in and to download a series of pages. For this, I used a library called Robobrowser.
I wrote this:

```
import robobrowser
import re

url = 'https://link.com/scp/login.php'

browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form(id='login')
form['userid'].value = 'login'
form['passwd'].value = 'Password'
browser.submit_form(form, submit='submit')
```

How can I get the session and keep it active? How to access the pages later?
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever figure how to keep the session active?  Or, how to access later pages?